# Count of previousSublings of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of elements

```
[
<tbody>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
<tr>​…​</tr>​
</tbody>​
]
```

After if i access some elements, for ex `$('tbody > tr:nth-child(5)')`, how do i get count of its previousSublings?

Comment: What do you mean by `Sublings`?

Comment: like .prevAll().length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amount of previous siblings `$('tbody > tr:nth-child(5)').prevAll().length`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
$( "tbody > tr:nth-child(5)" ).prevAll()
```

then count that array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prevAll().length` to get the number of preceding siblings

```
$('tbody > tr:nth-child(5)').prevAll('tr').length;
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XFxcp/)

Comment: 'tr' is not needed since there can not have any tag excepted tr elements isn't it ?!

Comment: @f00bar true. It's just a habit to inlcude the selector :)

Comment: Logically, if we are looking for the nth-child(x), couldn't we say their are x-1 children previous to this child?